# Left-aligned table of contents with section headings centered

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, sectioning

I was trying to center my section headings by using the command `\centering`, but I found that once the section headings are centered, the section names in the table of contents are also centered. Is there a way to keep the section names in the table of contents left-aligned while all the section headings are centered? (I only want the section headings to be centered and the headings of all other section levels to be left-aligned.) Below is an example code. Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{article}
\oddsidemargin =0cm \evensidemargin = 0cm \textwidth = 6.5in
\topmargin = 0in \textheight = 9in \headheight = 0in \headsep = 0in
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.0}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Example}



%\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}   % all section level below parts will not be numbered

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont}

\newcommand{\sectionalign}{\centering}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}
\hfill
\begin{center}
{\Large \bf 
This is an example
\vspace{6pt}}
\end{center}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{\protect \centering Section 1: \code{pip} and Virtual Environments}
\subsection{1. Introduction to \code{pip}}
This is an example
\end{document}
```

Comment: You wrote, "I found that once the headings are centered..." -- please tell us what you've done so far, including which document class you employ. Please also clarify whether only `section`-level headers should be centered horizontally in the document, or if `subsection`- and `subsubsection`-level headers should be centered as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback! I've updated my question statement and paste an example code. Hope it is more clear right now.

Comment: Thanks for these additional pieces of information. If I understand your code correctly, you want just `section`-level headers to be centered, whereas `subsubsection`-level entries should be left-aligned (or, possibly, fully justified. Is this impression correct?

Comment: Incidentally, how is `\code` defined?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I want subsubsection-level entries to be left-aligned.

Comment: I accidentally removed the code defining `\code` but I believe that does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

```
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
```

I don't have the reputation to comment on the original post, but looks like to use sectsty for this, you can just put `\centering` after `\selectfont` in your `\sectionfont` and `subsectionfont` commands. You don't need to redefine `\sectionalign` at all.

```
\sectionfont{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont\centering}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont\centering}
%\newcommand{\sectionalign}{\centering}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Does this instruction apply just to `section`-level headers or, more broadly, to all levels of sectioning headers (including `chapter`, `subsection`, and `subsubsection`?)

Comment: This command affects all levels of headers - there are more fine-grained controls in the package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now that works! The only thing is that after I used `\sectionfont{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont\centering}`, the heading of the table of contents (Contents) is centered, but I want it to be left-aligned. Could you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Move the \sectionfont line down after the \tableofcontents. It can come just before your first \section.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!